# Javascript return ascii character

Tags: javascript, ascii

How can I change the following to return ▼ using javascript

```
return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "&#x25BC Expand $50 to $900 &#x25BC";
```

I have tried to append with `.charCodeAt(0)` however not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/13358/

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: The strings are already in ascii. There's nothing about the strings that aren't ascii.

Comment: the value returned on the page doesn't show the corresponding character, i.e. ▼

Comment: So you want the corresponding UTF-8 character. That is quite the opposite of what your question title asks. So what stops you from doing `return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "▼ Expand $50 to $900 ▼";`

Comment: i did try, it return this â–¼

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has fixed the issue

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```